# Extbase: Ordering of translated records

Tags: typo3, extbase

I'ld like to order my records. I've already set the default ordering in the repository class:

```
protected $defaultOrderings = array(
    'title'=> Tx_Extbase_Persistence_QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING
);
```

But when creating a translation of a record with a different title, the output is still ordered by the titles of the default language. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

What version are you using? Since TYPO3 6.0 you can do the following:

```
$querySettings = $this->objectManager->get('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\Generic\\Typo3QuerySettings');

$querySettings->setSysLanguageUid(42);
```

Source: http://forge.typo3.org/projects/typo3v4-mvc/wiki/Default_Orderings_and_Query_Settings_in_Repository

Comment: Thank you for this hint. I am using TYPO3 4.7.14 and Extbase 4.7.7 and this function is not available there.